# Update Site address under Google cloud deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Our wordpress site hosted on Google Cloud VM Instance. We are accidentally stop and restart the VM Instance which cause the IP address change.

However, under the deployment tab, site address still point to the previous IP address, is anyone know how to update the site address under deployment tab to the new IP address, please?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ephemeral IPs are updated in the deployment section after VM reboots and changes IP. If your's does not show, you might wish to reboot your VM.
You can reserve a [static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) (they are free of charge as long as you use them actively). A static IP would fit better for a web server.